# Glide 4: get GifDecoder of GifDrawable

Tags: java, android, android-image, android-glide, image-loading

I'm looking to upgrade my app from Glide v3 to Glide v4. I need to know how long loop is of a `gif` that is loaded through Glide.

v3 Code:

```
int duration = 0;
GifDecoder decoder = gifDrawable.getDecoder();
for (int i = 0; i < gifDrawable.getFrameCount(); i++) {
    duration += decoder.getDelay(i);
}
```

It looks like the `GifDecoder` is no longer exposed with Glide v4. How do I go about calculating this without it, or how do I obtain the decoder now?

Comment: If i understood it correctly, you mean there is no `GifDecoder` with `Glide v4` right? If yes then it's wrong information; you can still use decoder there is no change in that. [Check the release changes](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases)

Comment: @Dipalis. AFAIK there is still a `GifDecoder`, it's just no longer exposed via the `Glide v4 API`. Meaning I can't access the object to get the frame information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a nasty way to acquire `GifDecoder` using reflection:

```
 Class gifStateClass = Class.forName("com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawable$GifState");
 Field frameLoaderField = gifStateClass.getDeclaredField("frameLoader");
 frameLoaderField.setAccessible(true);
 Object frameLoader = frameLoaderField.get(gifDrawable.getConstantState());

 Class frameLoaderClass = Class.forName("com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifFrameLoader");
 Field gifDecoderField = frameLoaderClass.getDeclaredField("gifDecoder");
 gifDecoderField.setAccessible(true);
 GifDecoder gifDecoder = (GifDecoder) gifDecoderField.get(frameLoader);

 int duration = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < gifDrawable.getFrameCount(); i++) {
     duration += gifDecoder.getDelay(i);
 }
```

This should **not** be considered as a stable/reliable solution as long as the API might change. Nevertheless, to quick solve the issue this will certainly work.

I can see an appropriate [issue opened](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2397), will update the answer as soon as something changes.

Comment: That is nasty... But it's the only working answer so you win the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link hope this helps:

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/third_party/gif_decoder/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/gifdecoder/GifDecoder.java

Please add below dependency:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
}
```

In above Gradle file decoder file is there and do your operations.

Comment: There is an implementation of the `GifDecoder` that is used internally by Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/third_party/gif_decoder/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/gifdecoder/StandardGifDecoder.java). It used to be exposed in v3 but is no longer exposed in v4. Your answer doesn't explain how to access the decoder.